# Json request firing a second time for a large request

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I'm using the following code to do some database processing and retrieve results:

```
$.getJSON('${fpfn:fullURL("user/uploadusers.json")}', {
            mod: '${param.mod}'
        }, function(data) {
            document.getElementById('appBody').style.cursor = '';
            corr = data.responses;
            });
```

However, the problem is that due to the heavy nature of the process request, I believe that the request is being resent after a specific time which is HIGHLY undesirable and results in duplicate values in the databse. Is there a flag or any value that I can set with the JSON request which would not fire the request the second time and keep waiting for the response?

Thanks!

Comment: It's *"HIGHLY"* unlikely that the size of the request or how long it's taking has anything to do with it being sent twice.

Comment: Hm, I'm quite sure that it is the size of the request because it's not doing it for smaller requests. However, could you suggest how to debug it?

Comment: How are you confirming that? there's absolutely nothing in the jQuery source that would re-send an ajax request in ANY event, unless your code initiated that second request. Daniele's answer might fix it, but it's just treating the symptoms, not really solving the real problem, therefore it could happen again.

Comment: I'm a JS novice. Ergo, the only difference I could see between the successful and the unsuccessful instances was the size of file. Anyhow, it'd be great if you can look at the code: http://jsfiddle.net/mgPsP/

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would cause it

Comment: Neither do I. The only (il)logical explanation being that it's because of the size of the request or could be something wrong with the browser. I'll try the solution Daniele suggested. Thanks for looking into this. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting a flag variable and handle on the variuous `$.getJSON` events:

```
var requestSent = false;

if(!requestSent) {
  requestSent = true;

  $.getJSON('${fpfn:fullURL("user/uploadusers.json")}', { mod: '${param.mod}' })
     .done( function(data) {
          requestSent = false;
          // ... YOUR CODE ...
       })
     .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
          requestSent = false;
          // ... YOUR CODE ...
       });
}
```